# Wildcard Endpoint URI in Oracle Service Bus (OSB)

Tags: oracle, osb

I am new to OSB and trying to create a proxy service which accepts wildcard as it's request endpoint URI and inturn calls the a business service with dynamic routing.

e.g.,  The proxy service should accept - **/someservice/wildcard1/service** and also **/someservice/wildcard2/service** and should be able to call the one business service with dynamic routing as http://businessip:port/someservice/wildcard1/service and http://businessip:port/someservice/wildcard2/service respectively.

Comment: OSB doesn't have that functionality. Workout another way to pass along the 'wilcardX' value and make it route it dynamicaly that way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no OSB OOTB functionality to expose one proxy service artifact under two different endpoint URI. Closest workaround for what you are trying to achive would be to use query part of URI. In more detail, you would need to call your service providing wildcard in query part of URI:

```
/someservice/service?wildcard=1
/someservice/service?wildcard=2
```

then in request pipeline you would extract wild card value from context variable
    $inbound/ctx:transport/ctx:request/http:query-parameters/http:parameter[@name="wildcard"]/@value 
and use it to either:

1. override context variable responsible for outbound
   URI($outbound/ctx:transport/ctx:uri) and route to BusinessService
2. build service path in dynamic routing

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly the perfect answer, but I read a really interesting article about using OSB to create RESTful interfaces: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/soa/architecting-restful-services-083025.html

This may apply somewhat to the problem you're having, as the article has a means to tease apart part of the URI path and then use that as a routing layer to another proxy service.

That said, you will likely have some issues as this grows bigger, because you will have to update this proxy every time you need to change it, add, or remove a new endpoint based on this architecture, so you may want to revisit how you're using this service, or at least make sure that the work you're putting into it is a one-and-done kind of thing, lest you end up with something like 20- or 50- separate branches on your Proxy Service.

Comment: If you're willing to sacrifice some compile-time certainty, you can use dynamic routes based on the URL path.